# Java 8 to 11 Upgrade: org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlFeature configure WARNING: JAX-B API not found . WADL feature is disabled

Tags: java, jaxb, glassfish, java-11

I am getting the below error while trying to upgrade a java project from 8 to 11.

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlFeature configure
WARNING: JAX-B API not found . WADL feature is disabled.
```

Tried adding the below dependencies as per the suggestions in the community,

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But the warning is still unresolved. Am I missing any additional dependencies? Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Have you tried setting **org.glassfish.jaxb** version same as **javax.xml.bind** ? I also recommend the following link for adding artifacts. https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#deployment-maven-coordinates

Comment: Are you using Jersey 2.x or Jersey 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in its [maven dependency information](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.3), the `jaxb-runtime` library requires `javax.activation` which became `jakarta.activation` after JEE rebranding.

Please, try including the following [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.0.1) in your `pom.xml`, I think it can be of help:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi @jccampanero, Thank you so much for your answer. I do have the dependency already as a part of my pom.xml. But i still face this error. Can you please help further?

Comment: Hi @VigneshTI. Sorry for the late reply. I am sorry to hear that it didn't work. The error clearly has to do with the impossibility of finding JAXB in the classpath. Please, see the corresponding source code [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/7b6d2f84391f24310baae7d8e55e644703642826/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/wadl/WadlFeature.java#L55-L58) and [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/7b6d2f84391f24310baae7d8e55e644703642826/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/ReflectionHelper.java#L1564-L1567). One thing you can try

Comment: is using the [Jakarta based java.xml.bind api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3) instead of the one you are using now with group id `javax.xml.bind`. In addition, can you provide further details about the jersey versions you are using in the question? I think it can be of relevance.

Comment: Hi @jccampanero, Thank you so much for your help in answering. Unfortunately, replacing with javax with jakarta based also did not work still. Current jetty version which I am using is 11.0.6 and Jersy version is 3.0.2

Comment: Hi @VigneshTI. You are welcome. Sorry to hear that again it didn't work. Your setup is almost exact to [the one  described in this article](https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-and-jetty-http-server-examples/) I came across some time ago. Please, can you review it? Maybe contrasting the different dependencies in your project and those proposed in the article can be of help.

Comment: In your project (assuming you have included the dependencies mentioned above), are you able to import the class `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable wadl feature if you don't use it.
by adding init param of `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` as following in your `web.xml`

```xml
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
```